# My first tab runs in the paragraph below. How to prevent this from happening?

Tags: html, css, overflow

On my first tab, you'll see if the text is long it will run into to the paragraph below it. How do I prevent this? I don't want the text in the First tab to run into the text below it.

I would like the paragraph to be moved below the tabbed area. I can edit the height in .nav-tabs:after, but is there an easier way of doing this?

I don't want it to scroll.

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/vm4d3a1q/32/

```css
.nav-tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-tabs:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 242px;
}
.nav-tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-tabs li > input {
  display: none;
}
.nav-tabs li > label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.nav-tabs li:last-child > label {
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e2e3e4;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
/* Functional */

.nav-tabs li > input:checked + label {
  background-color: #2251a4;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs li > input:checked ~ .nav-tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li>
    <input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tabs" type="radio" />
    <label for="tab-1">First</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum fuga porro placeat enim cumque nobis, eum atque suscipit optio quibusdam dolores recusandae! Ab fugiat deserunt explicabo expedita delectus labore illum.</p>
      <p>Harum facilis, dolore! Sed eligendi accusamus harum, earum error a praesentium! Esse laboriosam incidunt, suscipit possimus magnam nostrum voluptatem minima deserunt nisi, sint iste tenetur corporis itaque aspernatur neque explicabo.</p>
      <p>Nobis nihil dolores optio! Aperiam laudantium ipsam alias enim, omnis voluptatem laboriosam, repudiandae magni, quas, quos in repellendus delectus! Vel consequatur tempora aperiam earum temporibus nemo cupiditate laudantium laboriosam, eos.</p>
      <p>Quis eveniet delectus, earum rerum asperiores ducimus quos eaque ex tenetur corporis ullam hic quasi magni laborum necessitatibus impedit voluptates! Deleniti fuga aliquam ex. Reiciendis necessitatibus, obcaecati et labore aliquid.</p>
      <p>Fuga odit at nostrum molestias, inventore deserunt tempore quae cupiditate nulla voluptatem earum doloribus quia iste, eum dignissimos totam similique ea unde asperiores! Vero unde rem laboriosam repellat sunt. Vel.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tab-2" name="tabs" type="radio" />
    <label for="tab-2">Second</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, quae quas nemo veniam ullam magnam dolorum vero! Quod animi a, quidem nostrum, explicabo laboriosam distinctio ea sint recusandae, et voluptatibus.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tab-3" name="tabs" type="radio" />
    <label for="tab-3">Third</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa laborum dolore officiis assumenda nihil quas nam, molestiae est corrupti! Tenetur, recusandae enim hic itaque cupiditate nisi quidem inventore voluptatum neque.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tab-4" name="tabs" type="radio" />
    <label for="tab-4">Fourth</label>
    <div class="nav-tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa laborum dolore officiis assumenda nihil quas nam, molestiae est corrupti! Tenetur, recusandae enim hic itaque cupiditate nisi quidem inventore voluptatum neque.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum fuga porro placeat enim cumque nobis, eum atque suscipit optio quibusdam dolores recusandae! Ab fugiat deserunt explicabo expedita delectus labore illum. Harum facilis, dolore! Sed eligendi
  accusamus harum, earum error a praesentium! Esse laboriosam incidunt, suscipit possimus magnam nostrum voluptatem minima deserunt nisi, sint iste tenetur corporis itaque aspernatur neque explicabo. Nobis nihil dolores optio! Aperiam laudantium ipsam
  alias enim, omnis voluptatem laboriosam, repudiandae magni, quas, quos in repellendus delectus! Vel consequatur tempora aperiam earum temporibus nemo cupiditate laudantium laboriosam, eos.</p>
```

Comment: What *do* you want to happen? Should the tab be clipped, should the text below move down, or something else?

Comment: I'd like the paragraph below it be moved down. I know I can edit the height in the .nav-tabs:after to move it down, but is there an easier way?

Comment: One thing you can do is to put `overflow-y: auto;` on the `div` element. Then it will scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/vm4d3a1q/37/

Comment: I don't want it to scroll. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nav-tabs{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs:after{
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 height: 242px;
}

.nav-tabs li{
display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs li > input{
 display: none;
}

.nav-tabs li > label{
 display: inline-block;
 border: none;
 border-right-width: 0;
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs li:last-child > label{
 border-right-width: 1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-tab-content{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 border-top: 1px solid #e2e3e4;
 height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Functional */

.nav-tabs li > input:checked + label{
 background-color: #2251a4;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs li > input:checked ~ .nav-tab-content{
 display: block;
}
section{position:relative;
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs">
 <li>
  <input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-1">First</label>
  <div class="nav-tab-content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum fuga porro placeat enim cumque nobis, eum atque suscipit optio quibusdam dolores recusandae! Ab fugiat deserunt explicabo expedita delectus labore illum.</p>
   <p>Harum facilis, dolore! Sed eligendi accusamus harum, earum error a praesentium! Esse laboriosam incidunt, suscipit possimus magnam nostrum voluptatem minima deserunt nisi, sint iste tenetur corporis itaque aspernatur neque explicabo.</p>
   <p>Nobis nihil dolores optio! Aperiam laudantium ipsam alias enim, omnis voluptatem laboriosam, repudiandae magni, quas, quos in repellendus delectus! Vel consequatur tempora aperiam earum temporibus nemo cupiditate laudantium laboriosam, eos.</p>
   <p>Quis eveniet delectus, earum rerum asperiores ducimus quos eaque ex tenetur corporis ullam hic quasi magni laborum necessitatibus impedit voluptates! Deleniti fuga aliquam ex. Reiciendis necessitatibus, obcaecati et labore aliquid.</p>
   <p>Fuga odit at nostrum molestias, inventore deserunt tempore quae cupiditate nulla voluptatem earum doloribus quia iste, eum dignissimos totam similique ea unde asperiores! Vero unde rem laboriosam repellat sunt. Vel.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input id="tab-2" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-2">Second</label>
  <div class="nav-tab-content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, quae quas nemo veniam ullam magnam dolorum vero! Quod animi a, quidem nostrum, explicabo laboriosam distinctio ea sint recusandae, et voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input id="tab-3" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-3">Third</label>
  <div class="nav-tab-content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa laborum dolore officiis assumenda nihil quas nam, molestiae est corrupti! Tenetur, recusandae enim hic itaque cupiditate nisi quidem inventore voluptatum neque.</p>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <input id="tab-4" name="tabs" type="radio" /> <label for="tab-4">Fourth</label>
  <div class="nav-tab-content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa laborum dolore officiis assumenda nihil quas nam, molestiae est corrupti! Tenetur, recusandae enim hic itaque cupiditate nisi quidem inventore voluptatum neque.</p>
  </div>
 </li>    
</ul>
<section>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum fuga porro placeat enim cumque nobis, eum atque suscipit optio quibusdam dolores recusandae! Ab fugiat deserunt explicabo expedita delectus labore illum.

Harum facilis, dolore! Sed eligendi accusamus harum, earum error a praesentium! Esse laboriosam incidunt, suscipit possimus magnam nostrum voluptatem minima deserunt nisi, sint iste tenetur corporis itaque aspernatur neque explicabo.

Nobis nihil dolores optio! Aperiam laudantium ipsam alias enim, omnis voluptatem laboriosam, repudiandae magni, quas, quos in repellendus delectus! Vel consequatur tempora aperiam earum temporibus nemo cupiditate laudantium laboriosam, eos.</section>
```

i turned your end piece into a section and put the following styling onto it

```
section{position:relative;
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;}
```

when you widen the screen in jsfiddle it doesn't scroll http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/vm4d3a1q/38/

Comment: or view the snippet full screen